# Trying to Create a Delayed Pop-up with Lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, lightbox

I'm trying to create a lightbox with Jquery that will open an email collection pop-up to sign up for a newsletter.  I think I understand how to make it work if someone clicks on a link but I don't want the visitor to have to click a link, I want it to pop up automatically after say a 5 second delay when the visitor lands on the page as seems common on many pages.  This is a non CMS page.  Can someone tell me the simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimout()` for that :

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //This code will run in 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwxdrrLf/) with an alert to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks ... where it says "5 secs later.. " in the fiddle I couldn't just add a path to a webpage there instead of text could I?  Also I thought lightboxes were supossedly more user friendly?  If what I said was possible and I sent to a form instead of just an alert text, would that be a red flag for pop-up blockers and web protection software?

Comment: I only used an alert for demonstration purposes. :) You can put whatever code you want, it doesn't have to be an alert, it can be a lightbox, it can be a console.log(), it can be any JS code!

Comment: That's cool but I still don't get how to make it interact with lightbox as they only mention initializing the light box like this `<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>` and there's no mention of a way to initialize it with only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this add this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){ popupFunction(); }, 5000);
```

to your jquery window ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //add code here
   setTimeout(function(){ popupFunction(); }, 5000);
});
```

And then create a function that makes your popup work:

```
function popupFunction(){ 
  //code here that works the popup
}
```

Comment: I think I'm missing part of the equation.  On the lightbox site I only see it showing how to call it like this:  'code'<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>'code' but it seems you're saying there is another way to call it using only jquery.  Sorry I'm brand new this.  I was thinking to just replace the image path with a path to a php document and send it to the server as normal from there.  I don't understand where I would put the path to the page using javascript

Comment: What lightbox version are you using? Provide the website as well.

Comment: lightbox 2 I'm looking under where it says "initialize with html" http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: You could always add a hidden div and link and use jquery's `click` event: `$( "#target" ).click();` on the <a> ID

Comment: Ok don't know how to do that yet, but I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: I, personally, dislike litebox. I'd suggest [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) because everything comes pre-styled